# jQuery (document).ready() changed in jQuery 3.0?

Tags: jquery, performance

I saw recently after jQuery 3.0 release, everyone replaced the $ in

```
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {});
```

What is the difference? will the second method work with jQuery 2.1.4?

Comment: `$`  is a shorthand for `jQuery`. While `jQuery` should always work, the `$` might be overwritten by another library.

Comment: thx! I just see jQuery(document) a lot more now...

Comment: For tutorials and example code it is useful because then it is obvious that the code is about jQuery and not another library.

Comment: No, this change has nothing to do with jQuery 3.0, it's always been a best practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best practice to avoid conflicts with other libraries using this kind of document.ready(), so  $ in here will be an locally-scoped alias to jQuery.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    //code...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Second method works already from version 1.

I use this options always because $ can be used with other libraries as well and you have conflict.

Comment: Please mark comment as correct if it works for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Listed below three function are same  [JQuery ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

})
```

and

```
$(function(){

});
```

and

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    // will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.


});
```